# Regex to match a function

Tags: ruby, regex

I need a regex to find a function written in a file. For example, the file content is this:

```
include('a.rb') some code
```

The regex I tried to find whether `include` is used or not in the file is `scan(/include( )* \(/)`. It works, but it fails with some functions like `test_include()`. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: most likely you are solving wrong problem. try to tell "real" task you want to solve.

Comment: I need to found whether a PHP file uses `require()` function or not. For this i tried above regex but it fails when there is function with name `test_include()`. I mean when there is no function `include()` but `test_include()` is there, this case it says `include()` is found but actually it is not present. @iced

Comment: Sounds like you need word boundaries, as in `\binclude()`.  This would not match your `test_include()` example.

Comment: Your question should be something like this: "I wish to match a string of the form 'include(...)', where '...' refers to any number of any characters other than `)`. Moreover, the characters immediately preceding the string must... How can I do that?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to match any function names, according to [Ruby method naming conventions](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#naming), you can try this code:

```
line = "include('a.rb') some code";

if ( line =~ /[a-zA-Z_]+\([^\)]*\)/ )
  puts "line contains include function"
end
```

To avoid matching "test_" in "test_include()", you need a negative lookbehind:

```
/(?<!test_)include\([^\)]*\)/
```

or, you can set an anchor:

```
/\binclude\([^\)]*\)/
```

Comment: The OP has no problems to match such line. He failed at matching `test_**include**`

Comment: I need to it to match only `include()` not `test_include()` . when i use your regex it tell match found. As said by VMAtm

Comment: @Vijay: I updated my answer according to your feedback to iced.